# How did Banner get unstuck?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, the-incredible-hulk, avengers-infinity-war

In the final battle of *Avengers: Infinity War,* Banner charges at Thanos, who dodges by shifting phase, much like Vision can. However, instead of Thanos shifting phase himself, it looks like he uses the Infinity Gauntlet to phase *Banner* and fling him into a mountainside.

The scene then cuts away, and I immediately presumed that Banner was entombed in the mountainside and left for dead – it’s a common comics trope for out-of-phase characters to get stuck in things and die unless rescued quickly.

> However, in the next scene, Banner simply reappears as if nothing happened.

Was there an explanation for this that I missed, or a deleted scene, or is it a continuity error?

Comment: You might consider changing the accepted answer here if you want as it is incorrect, Thanos does not use the Reality Stone on Banner.

Comment: I’m not convinced that it’s incorrect. Yes, Thanos clearly uses the Space stone to fling Banner, but that’s not the effect I’m asking about. Only the Reality stone produces temporary spellbinding effects like in this scene, so either he used a combination of stones or it’s a continuity error, and none of other answers address that.

Comment: He only uses the Space Stone on Banner. There's no indication it _was_ a temporary effect, Banner could have just smashed his way free, we don't know because it happens off screen. I've tried to be as detailed as possible in my answer, if there's something you think I've missed let me know :)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

I believe it was the Reality Stone that he used.

> Just as Drax and Mantis were torn apart by the Reality Stone by Thanos on Knowhere, once he left they went back to normal. So once he left Wakanda, the Stone returned Banner and the Hulkbuster back to normal.

Comment: I don't think this is the case - as I was watching last night [it's the space stone he used](https://i.stack.imgur.com/soi7N.jpg) when moving Banner. I'm still curious as to the explanation...maybe we'll find out in April?

Comment: @NickCraver - You are correct, sir. Which means that this answer is simply wrong

Answer (score 18):

The only reasonable answer here is simply that we simply don't know. I can think of two possible theories for how he could have escaped, though I'm leaning more towards the first as being the most likely.

- The Hulkbuster armour is simply stronger than the amount of rock holding it in place. The rock only really covers the limbs and some of the edges of the suit and even then it's not that much over the suit itself. It is likely that it merely incapacitated him long enough that Thanos could do the Snap and then Banner was able to free himself.

  [image: Banner phased into the mountain]
- The effects of the stone wear of when Thanos leaves. Like with Drax and Mantis on Knowwhere with the Reality Stone the effects of the Space Stone could have worn off when Thanos left the area. I don't think this holds true with the Space Stone like it does the Reality Stone though.

For what it's worth Thanos also uses the Space Stone on Rhodey to crush the suit and move him out of the way and we later on he looks fine again. This actually backs up both theories as both effects are from the same Infinity Stone and both are Stark's suits.

We can also rule out a few possibilities:

- [He uses the Reality Stone](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/186703/58193): This is incorrect as we clearly see him using the Space Stone.

  [image: Thanos uses the Space Stone against Banner in the Hulkbuster suit]
- [He ejects from the suit](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/186816/58193): This is incorrect as we see him in the suit later on.

  [image: Banner in the Hulkbuster suit after the Snap and Thanos' departure]
- [He was meant to be Hulk at that point](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/205048/58193): Whilst I quite like this as an out of universe theory the director's explicitly deny it and it doesn't explain what we actually see on screen.
- The Time Stone reversed time for everyone: This is incorrect as we see Wanda clearly unaffected by the Time Stone's effects right next to Thanos. The Time Stone is simply reversing time on the destroyed Mind Stone and that alone.

Comment: I appreciate the thorough analysis and have upvoted, but unfortunately “we simply don’t know” still leaves the original question to answer.

Answer (score 12):

### In an earlier version of the film He pulled himself free *as the Hulk*. The film then left this as a hanging plot point because the Hulk was edited out of the final cut.

We now know that there was a scene where the Hulk finally emerges and busts out of the Hulkbuster suit during his fight with Cull Obsidian, as evidenced by some recently released early VFX footage showing Banner emerging from the Hulkbuster suit as Smart Hulk ("*We worked it out*").

[image: Shot showing Ruffalo in a motion capture suit, with a smaller picture-within-picture of Smark Hulk busting out of the Hulkbuster suit]

We also have this still (from the [cinematic trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=122&v=6ZfuNTqbHE8)), showing a veritable army (including the Hulk) charging toward Thanos in the forest and various toys designed before the film was changed in post-production.

[image: shot from the trailer of the Hulk in the midst of an army, with Bucky, Captain America, Black Widow, Okoye, and Black Panther at the front]

[image: Infinity War-branded action figure box showing the Hulk and the Hulkbuster suit]

[image: Infinity War-branded action figure showing the Hulk breaking out of the Hulkbuster suit]

We also have confirmation from the screenplay writer that this change was intended ***and filmed***, and only fixed in post-production VFX at a later date.

> Originally scheduled for a last-minute arrival in Infinity War, Banner
> and Hulk were going to strike a deal during the Battle of Wakanda.
> Professor Hulk was supposed to tear out of the Hulkbuster armor and KO
> Cull Obsidian.
>
> Speaking on the Endgame commentary, McFeely said, “It was pretty clear
> that the movie could not handle this weird success. The movie needed
> to just stay in its succession of losses in the third act, which meant
> some hustling on the part of VFX late in the game."
>
> <sub><sup>[All the Infinity War storylines that got dropped before the final draft](https://www.digitalspy.com/movies/a28587937/infinity-war-alternate-ending/)</sup></sub>

While the directors [deny that this scene was actually part of the movie(!)](https://www.flickeringmyth.com/2018/05/the-hulk-in-wakanda-shot-in-the-avengers-infinity-war-trailer-was-a-deliberate-redirect/), It seems more likely that in the earlier cut he was fully 'hulked' when Thanos zapped him into the rock.

Given the Hulk's constitution and rapid healing, being phased into a wall wouldn't *kill* him but would, presumably incapacitate him for a while, [nerfing](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=nerfed) him until the fight with Thanos had already concluded, **at which point he could just pull himself free.**

Comment: I think this is a speculative answer, the directors denied that the scene with the Hulk was part of the movie, what make you think the opposite ?

Comment: @DhonJoe - The presence of multiple toys showing the Hulk emerging from the suit.

Comment: is the presence of a toy an official source ?

Comment: @DhonJoe - No, but given how much 'lead time' you need in order to make the merchandise for high CGI films, it's quite regular for cut scenes to end up with merchandise, for example the "Finn and Rey in a landspeeder" toy you can get from the cutscene for Force Awakens

Comment: @DhonJoe - the fact that there is near identical merchandise that relates to something not in the film *from two separate companies* is very suspicious indeed

Comment: If he hulked out, the hulkbuster would in pieces

Comment: @DhonJoe - We now have confirmation that they were lying/mistaken - "*Originally scheduled for a last-minute arrival in Infinity War, Banner and Hulk were going to strike a deal during the Battle of Wakanda. Professor Hulk was supposed to tear out of the Hulkbuster armor and KO Cull Obsidian. Speaking on the Endgame commentary, McFeely said, “It was pretty clear that the movie could not handle this weird success. The movie needed to just stay in its succession of losses in the third act, which meant some hustling on the part of VFX late in the game.""*

Comment: @Valorum "cut scene" and "cutscene" are quite different things.

Answer (score 1):

Banner wasn't phased *deep* into the mountain - in the scene you see him phased back in with the front of the suit still showing. I presumed he was safe inside the suit and eventually managed to eject.

Comment: I'm quite sure we see the whole suit free of the mountain afterward (well, less an arm, I think), so it's not that he ejected.

Answer (score 1):

Basically everything from the moment where Thanos causes Bruce to get stuck in the rock, Natasha being trapped under the rock pillars, Cap being hit in the head, etc. was reversed when Thanos used the Time Stone to reverse the Mind Stone being destroyed in Vision's head.

Comment: This seems ...plausible, but can you back it up with any actual evidence?